# How to combine outputs of 24 independently trained random forests outputs

Tags: neural-networks, random-forest, transfer-learning

Imagine I have 24 random forest classification models trained on classifying two classes Y=1 and Y=0. Each model learns on independent data, each model learns on same number of observations and same class balance. Parameters of each of 24 models is different, precision and recall of all 24 models are also different due to different data. I am trying to find the hour at which to perform certain action. Currently, I run 24 models that independently output a probability. This probability is the percentage of trees out of all trees that voted for a class Y=1. The hour (model) with the highest probability is chosen as the hour at which I will perform a certain action.
My problem with current setup is the fact that I am using argmax function on models that might not be comparable? Thus, I have 3 questions:

1. How can I continue using argmax function by making models comparable?
2. How can I add weights to probability outputs to reflect the fact the different models have different precision?
3. Is there a better way to incorporate information from other models?

If you have any other contribution that does not answer above question, I would gladly read them. Thank you very much for reading and perhaps answering.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have some data associated with each hour of the day, and you have trained 24 different random forests (one for each hour) to predict whether or not you "should" undertake a certain action during that hour.  You are currently using a decision rule of "go with whichever forest had the most trees in agreement".

I think that this entire approach is really flawed and you should go back to square one.

There is no reason that "percentage of trees voting together" in one model should be comparable to another.  Even with just one model, this percentage of trees voting together doesn't correspond to a probability of obtaining the correct class.  All of the trees could be just *slightly* to one side of the decision boundary and you would have 100% of trees predicting 1 on one side and 0% of trees predicting 1 on the other side.

If you have hourly data and you want to decide which *one* hour to take a certain action you should design your prediction system to take all of the data and return one of the 24 classes.  Your model will need to directly compare predictor variables across each of the 24 classes to make a decision.

Comment: Not entirely correct understanding. 24 models were trained to predict whether Y=1 or Y=0. The decision rule to undertake the action at a given hour is indeed  given by: go with performing the action at the hour which has the highest probability of Y=1

Comment: Are the 24 models each corresponding to one hour?

Comment: Yes , that is correct

Comment: @MSKO I think all of my advice still stands!